# Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Goslate'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-module, goslate

I am trying **Goslate: Free Google Translate API**. I installed goslate using `sudo pip install goslate`

I wrote a simple program and executed it using `python getbn.py` command in my terminal.

Here is the code inside `getbn.py`:

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()
print(gs.translate('hello world', 'bn'))
```

After executing the command `python getbn.py` I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getbn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import goslate
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/goslate.py", line 2, in <module>
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Goslate'
```

Then I tried to run the program by executing `python3 getbn.py`command, and I found the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getbn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import goslate
ImportError: bad magic number in 'goslate': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

How do I fix it? And why are there two different types of erros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file called `goslate.py` in your `Desktop` folder

```
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/goslate.py", line 2, in <module>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is not the module you installed using `pip` and it's getting in the way of the import.

Comment: When I run `pip install goslate` it shows as following:



`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): goslate in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from goslate)
Cleaning up...`

Answer (score 0):

You May have simple installed goslate, but you may be using different virtual env. Try to switch to that virtual env, and then run again.